# Spring Boot Auto generated MySQL database

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, mysqli

I'm trying to auto generate the database based on POJO classes :

**Director Model :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "director")
public class Director extends AuditModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "age", nullable = false)
    private int age;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "photo", nullable = false)
    private String photo;

    //Getters & Setters
}
```

**Movie Model :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movie")
public class Movie extends AuditModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "story", nullable = false)
    private String story;

    @Column(name = "photo", nullable = false)
    private String photo;

    @Column(name = "releaseYear", nullable = false)
    private int releaseYear;

    @Column(name = "rating", nullable = false)
    private float rating;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "director", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Director director;

    //Getters & Setters
}
```

And here **Audit Model** which have Temporal fields like created_at ...

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"}, allowGetters = true)
public abstract class AuditModel implements Serializable {
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false, columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedAt;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

And here's my configuration in **application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_boot_movies
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
```

I'm using `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` to auto-generate the database.
Now the database is generated good, but the foreign key is generated as a simple integer field.

Comment: For your foreign key generated as a simple integer field, have you tried to add @Type(type = "long") on top of your ids ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have ManyToOne but OneToMany is missing in Director Class

In your Director Class you should add something like this

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = “director”)
private List<Director> items;
```

and Can you try `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`

It will delete all MySQL tables and Create new Tables. Later on CHange back to `update`

Comment: can you check Log...  There must be some error while generating Foreign Key.     you can add this propery to enable mysql query in Console..  spring.jpa.show-sql=true

Answer (score 0):

It is correct behaviour. In database foregin key references primary key from other table. In your case it is an integer. The primary - foregin key relation is turned into objects association  (and vice versa) by ORM framework.

Comment: yeah but when i check the database, there's no foreign key, is just an integer field, i can enter a new movie record without having any director, i can enter any value i want in the director field and that's wrong ! but the query executed successfully !

Comment: You can enter it into database because there is no integrity constraints autogenerated. But if you try to create Movie entity in application and save it to database, you'll get an error.